# Getting two different objects when splitting NLTK data into two lists

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to split a NLTK list, but the split lists are resolving into two different types. The first list returns class 'nltk.collections.LazySubsequence', and the second list returns class 'list.' I would like both lists to be of type list, how would I do this? Also, why is the first list turning into an 'nltk.collections.LazySubSequency" object?

```
import nltk

def novel10(words):
    first_list = words[:int(len(words)*.90)]
    second_list = words[int(len(words)*.90):]
    print(type(first_list))
    print(type(second_list))

words = nltk.corpus.udhr.words("English-Latin1")

novel10(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that **words** is actually a `nltk.corpus.reader.util.StreamBackedCorpusView`.  You want to first convert this to a list and then do your slicing.  Here's revised code..

```
import nltk
def novel10(corp_view):
    words = list(corp_view)
    split = int(len(words)*.9)
    first_list = words[:split]
    second_list = words[split:]
    print(type(first_list),  len(first_list),  first_list[:4],  '..')
    print(type(second_list), len(second_list), second_list[:4], '..')

corp_view = nltk.corpus.udhr.words("English-Latin1")
novel10(corp_view)
```